# Для чего нужен тип `wchar_t`?

Tags: c++, типы-данных

Для чего нужен тип данных `wchar_t`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Проще говоря, этот тип используется для представления значений расширенных наборов символов, которые соответствуют национальным языкам.

В настоящее время стандарт C++ поддерживает следующие типы для представления  знаков наборам символов, включая расширенные наборы, как, например, символы 
UNICODE:

```
char, char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t
```

Пример использования "широкого" строкового литерала

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const wchar_t *s = L"Hello, World!";

    std::wcout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ясно, а можно пример какой-нибудь?

Comment: @gsfdgsfdg Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: А для чего `L` и почему двойные кавычки?

Comment: @gsfdgsfdg Двойные кавычки означают строковый литерал, а символ L перед ним означает широкий строковый литерал.